# MATCH AGAINST not working with two LEFT JOIN: #1210 - Incorrect arguments to MATCH

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I have three tables in my MySQL database: `books`, `authors` and `cities`.

`books` has the columns: `id`, `author_id`

`authors` has the columns: `id`, `author`, `city_id`

`cities` has the columns: `id`, `city`

Running

```
SELECT *, books.id, authors.author FROM books LEFT JOIN authors ON books.author_id = authors.id WHERE MATCH (authors.author) AGAINST ("peter" IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

via SQL tab in phpMyAdmin everything works fine.

But taking another `LEFT JOIN` like

```
SELECT *, books.id, authors.author, cities.city FROM books LEFT JOIN authors ON books.author_id = authors.id LEFT JOIN cities ON authors.city_id = cities.id WHERE MATCH (authors.author, cities.city) AGAINST ("peter" IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

I'm getting the error message

> MySQL said: Documentation
>
> #1210 - Incorrect arguments to MATCH

I made many tests and it seems like `MATCH AGAINST` doesn't work with two `LEFT JOIN`. But I couldn't find anything in the internet. I also tried to use `JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN` but without success.

All columns definitely exist.

Any idea what I can do?

If any more information needed, just ask.

Comment: Can you provide a sample data for above mentioned tables?

Comment: @Aurelian While trying to create a sample SQL file I found the solution: see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution: column `cities` was `InnoDB` instead of `MyISAM` as the other tables are.